# Implementing Google maps in mobile

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, compact-framework

How to show google maps in mobile application using .net2.0

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) tutorial link into the Android website about the Maps API may be of assistance.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple approach is to use the [Google Maps Static API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), a [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [Image.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) to download an image of the map, e.g. "http://maps.google.com/staticmap?zoom=14&size=512x512&mapt
ype=mobile&markers=40.714728,-73.998672&key=YOUR-GOOGLE-MAPS-API-KEY" which can be shown in a [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx).

Regards,
tamberg

Comment: Saving is against Maps TOS.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but you might find this helpful as well:

http://www.koushikdutta.com/2008/07/virtual-earth-and-google-maps-tiled-map.html

Should give you a bit more flexibility (zooming, moving around, etc... ) than the static maps API.

Answer (score 1):

Do the maps absolutly have to be from Google?  I was writing an application that made use of Live Maps to display maps on a Compact Framework application.  When I wrote the app I used the 3.5 framework though, so I am not sure whether or not this will fit your needs.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/WiMoWifiPosition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is various controls available to integrate Google Maps into an ASP.net website. Since the Sockets and Net libraries are available on Windows Mobile, you could possibly integrate using the Google Maps API, however will have to build your own controls to display the maps. The API can be found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/).